# What is the function “oneflag_：0” in this expression？

Tags: functions, matrix

[image]

[image]

The first function  Pivotdown can zero out all entries in a column below a desired location.  But l don't know the function of “oneflag _0".

Comment: That screenshot is very hard to read, because it is small, but for the `oneflag_ : 0` syntax, read [this page of the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html). (I'm not entirely sure that it actually says `oneflag_ : 0`, but I can't read it very well, so I guessed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you see a function prototype with a formal argument  of the form `oneflag_ : 0`, it means the actual argument can be of any type (or more precisely have any head), but if it is omitted, then the value 0 will be used. Look up [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) in the documentation.